# Add jQuery-Knob in Angular 2

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate, jquery-knob

I am new to Angular 2.0 and using `aspnetboilerplate` template.

I am trying to integrate `jQuery-Knob`.

First, I included `jquery.knob.min.js` in `scripts` in `.angular-cli.json`:

```
"scripts": 
[
    "../src/bsb-theme/js/jquery.validate.js",
    "../src/bsb-theme/js/jquery.knob.min.js"
]
```

Then, I made an `input` in `dashboard.component.html`:

```
<input type="text" class="knob" value="40"
    data-width="125"
    data-height="125"
    data-thickness="0.25"
    data-angleArc="250"
    data-angleoffset="-35"
    data-fgColor="#00BCD4">
```

But the output is a text box only.

Comment: Try calling `$('.knob').knob();`

Comment: i tried that one also but not working

Comment: is there any need to include it in app.module.ts if needed how to do that

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work out-of-the-box with Angular 2. Try this library: https://github.com/xzegga/angular2-knob

Comment: ok let me try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery-Knob` doesn't work out-of-the-box with Angular 2.

Try this library: https://github.com/xzegga/angular2-knob

---

## Usage

#### IMPORTING ANGULAR MODULE:

```js
import { KnobModule } from "angular2-knob";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [KnobModule]
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

#### HTML USE:

```js
<div ui-knob [value]="value" [options]="knOptions"></div>
```

#### CONFIGURING OPTIONS IN ANGULAR COMPONENT:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
  knOptions = {
    readOnly: true,
    size: 140,
    unit: '%',
    textColor: '#000000',
    fontSize: '32',
    fontWeigth: '700',
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    valueformat: 'percent',
    value: 0,
    max: 100
    trackWidth: 19,
    barWidth: 20,
    trackColor: '#D8D8D8',
    barColor: '#FF6F17',
    subText: {
      enabled: true,
      fontFamily: 'Verdana',
      font: '14',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      text: 'Overall',
      color: '#000000',
      offset: 7
    },
  }
  value = 45; 
}
```